# Prevent public List property from adding items

Tags: c#, list, collections

Is it possible to prevent a public property of the type `IList<>` from adding items. For example i have this simple code, which stores some instances in a simple list:

```
class Program
{
    private static IList<SomeItem> items = new List<SomeItem>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // That ok
        Items.Add(new SomeItem { OrderId = 0 });
        Items.Add(new SomeItem { OrderId = 1 });
        Items.Add(new SomeItem { OrderId = 2 });

        Console.WriteLine("Amount: {0}", items.Count);

        // This should not be possible
        OrderedList.Add(new SomeItem { OrderId = 3 });
        OrderedList.Add(new SomeItem { OrderId = 4 });

        Console.WriteLine("Amount: {0}", items.Count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static IList<SomeItem> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
    }

    public static IList<SomeItem> OrderedList
    {
        get
        {
            return items.OrderBy(item => item.OrderId).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

My API should expose some property, which returns a list of ordered items (`OrderedList`). This is all fine, but it should not be possible to add items to this list, because they will not be stored in `items`. Should i create my own read only list or am i missing some better solution. Thank you very much!

**EDIT**

In short: this should not be possible: `OrderedList.Add(new SomeItem { OrderId = 4 });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `IList<T>` can't be added, that's in fact `IReadOnlyList<T>`:

```
public static IReadOnlyList<SomeItem> OrderedList {  
  get {
    // IList<T> implements IReadOnlyList<T>, so just return List here
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: In 9 minutes. So let's wait :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of publishing the `IList<T>`, I'd propose to keep the list internal and only publish a `IReadOnlyList<T>`:

```
public static IReadOnlyList<SomeItem> OrderedList
{
    get
    {
        return items.OrderBy(item => item.OrderId).ToList().AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

You can use the [AsReadOnly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75(v=vs.110).aspx) method to create a readonly version of your list. This way, you return a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` so the caller is unable to cast the property value to an `IList<T>`. Otherwise the caller can do this cast and add items nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you! If i return `IReadOnlyList` i do not need `.AsReadOnly();`. But when using `var` it will be helpful!

Comment: @BendEg please see my latest edit; if you do the `AsReadOnly()` you return a ReadOnlyCollection; depends on how safe you want your interface to be.